# Can't see what I type after run "debugfs"

Tags: command-line

I use Ubuntu 14.04 and yesterday I tried to find out create time of a folder using `debugfs`.

```
debugfs -R 'stat <inod>' device
```

after I get the result of that in terminal, if I use <kbd>Q</kbd> for exit it's fine, but if I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> then I can't see what I'm typing in terminal until I close it and open another one.

It gets typed but I can't see it. why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably `debugfs` messed with terminal configuration. The command `reset` should fix it. Just type `reset`, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.